# ImportError: No module named paramiko

Tags: python, redhat, paramiko

I have installed "python-paramiko" and "python-pycrypto" in Red hat linux. 
But still when i run the sample program i get "ImportError: No module named paramiko".

I checked the installed packages using below command and got confirmed.

```
ncmdvstk:~/pdem $ rpm -qa | grep python-p
python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el3.rf
python-pycrypto-2.3-1.el3.pp
```

My sample program which give the import error:

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('127.0.0.1', username='admin', 
    password='admin')
```

Comment: What does sys.path contain? Where is the paramiko library on your system?

Comment: Also, does the version of the interpreter you used to try that code match the version of the python-paramiko module?

Comment: Execute the following from a shell prompt: python -c "from pprint import pprint; import sys; pprint(sys.path); Then edit your question with the output from this command!  Also provide the output from "which python".

Comment: >>> print(sys.path);
['', '/usr/lib/python2.2', '/usr/lib/python2.2/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.2                                                      /lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.2/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.2/site-pack                                                           ages/gtk-2.0']

Comment: OK, is paramiko in any of those locations?

Comment: Python 2.2 is quite an old version. It would be good to know if there are other version of python installed (perhaps paramiko is installed in one of them). (This is basically what @naeg was saying). Have a look in /usr/lib/ for any folders like python*. Also try "locate paramiko" and _update_ your answer with all this info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all these packages were installed outside the python folder.
And all I did was linking the packages from python folder to packages folder.

It worked perfectly.