# RuntimeWarning: in python 2.6 while importing python-pycrypto-2.3-1.el3.pp

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko, pycrypto

I have installed "python-pycrypto-2.3-1.el3.pp" and "python-paramiko-1.7.6-1.el3.rf" in red hat linux and using python2.6 version.

And when I import paramiko, I get below RuntimeWarning mismatch:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/SHAd256.py:38: 
RuntimeWarning: Python C API version mismatch for module Crypto.Hash.SHA256: This Python has API version 1013, module Crypto.Hash.SHA256 has version 1011.
```

please help how to resolve this problem.

Comment: You've clearly fixed the import issue for a previous question you've raised here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553700/importerror-no-module-named-paramiko. Please either update the previous question if it still concerns you or update it to indicate it's been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

The EL3 packages are for EL3 Python. Since you've installed Python from source yourself, perform a source installation of those modules.