# Python 2.7.11 ImportError: No module named paramiko

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, module, paramiko

so here is the deal. I have install pycrypto via pip (sudo pip install paramiko) for python 2.7.11. When I do "pip list" I see pycrypto installed. Screen shot below.  My problem is when I try to import pycrypto, my python gags and says

> ImportError: No module named paramiko

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: May be [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991319/ubuntu-python-no-module-named-paramiko) or [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553700/importerror-no-module-named-paramiko) could help you?

Comment: Are you sure you have one Python installed on your machine? Can you check on where pip is installed by typing `pip --version` in the command line and do `import sys; print sys.path` in the python shell to make sure they both point to same python version?

Comment: I have just checked, while I have Python 2.7 and paramiko installed on my PC, the demoe here https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/README.rst does not run either, I get a "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" in line 2

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip --version
pip 1.5.6 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Apr 13 2016, 04:36:55) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']